# How can I stop Entity Framework caching my data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, ninject

Before anyone marks this as a duplicate answer, please read it carefully, as I haven't yet found a question that deals with this scenario...

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application in VS2013 that uses EF6. Everything below refers to my debugging sessions, not to any deployed instances. This is all on my dev machine via VS and SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio.

The MVC project has injected (using Ninject) instances of business logic layers, and these in turn have injected repositories. The repositories query the database via EF.

I added some data to the database directly (ie from SSMS, not via code in the application), and it showed up on the web site correctly. I then modified the data, again via SSMS, and this time the web site showed duplicate entries, where I know for definite there aren't any.

I know about context caching, so stopped the debug run and pressed f5 again in Visual Studio, thinking that this would destroy the context and create a new one in the new debugging session - duplicate data still shown.

Hmm, I restarted VS, as that will kill off any context and web servers running, and tried again - duplicate data STILL shown.

Hmm, let's try restarting SQL Server - same problem (not that I expected this to work, but I was out of ideas by now).

So I'm baffled. I understand how and why the EF context caches data, but how does that survive VS being restarted? I haven't yet restarted the machine, but other than that, I don't seem to be able to get it to clear the cache.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps there is a bug in your code? Could you narrow it down a bit, and post the smallest code fragments which reproduce the problem?

Comment: Without code it is difficult to tell, but it doesn't sound like a caching issue, ef does not persist data in memory if you restart the process. "duplicate" data in the application but not in the database sounds like some kind of join is is joining multiple times per row. Just a stab in the dark though, please post code.

Comment: It turned out that EF was pulling in child entities in a place where I didn't expect it to, and when I did myEntity.Stuff = someStuff, it was combining the someStuff collection with the existing Stuff collection instead of just replacing it. Weird, but once I realised it was pulling in the child entities, I didn't need my extra code anyway, so the problem went away. Like you both said, nothing to do with caching in the end. Thanks anyway for your suggestions.